# "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" when querying unless adding @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I just have a new project to maintain, and using Hibernate+Spring. I wrote a DeliveryInfoServiceImpl which have a method to query for some entity but not have any update or save operation, but I have an error:

```
Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

Unless I add @Transactional on the method or the class.

My questions are :

1. Why I have to add `@Transactional` though I am only executing select query?
2. Does adding `@Transactional` means enable transaction support ,which may have more unnecessary overhead when I am only using "select" query.

Below is my code snippet:

```
@Override
public List<UnavailableRestaurantBean> getUnavailableRestaurantBean(String custAddress, List<Long> dishesId) {
    List<Dish> dishes = getDishByIds(dishesId);//exception here
    .... 

}


private List<Dish> getDishByIds(List<Long> ids){
    return deliveryInfoDao.findByIds(Dish.class,ids);
}
```

And I have below transaction manager config:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />

<bean id="myTxManager" name="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: To remove unnecessary overhead, use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`, Hibernate will not got for dirty check

Comment: @kamil , why have I add Transactional in this case , actually some will not throw error even though I do not add this annotation.

Comment: @Jaskey possibly because those methods are called somewhere inside another method which is transactional? It works on an inheritance basis, as long as somewhere in the callstack a method or class declares itself transactional, any methods called inside it will adopt that transactional state (and share the session).